# How to retrieve video view counts from YouTube API

Tags: google-api, youtube-api

I am currently exploring the use of Google's YouTube API to retrieve view counts from YouTube channels.(Google.Apis.Youtube.v3.dll) . I can successfully retrieve information about videos in the channels but cannot retrieve actual viewcounts.

Example:

```
foreach (var channel in channelsListResponse.Items)
  {
   var viewcount = channel.Statistics.ViewCount;
```

I keep getting an "object reference not set to an instance of an object" error.

Does anyone have a .net code example retrieving view counts using the YouTube API or know what may be causing such an error?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you? It retrieves all info of a users profile https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet#Retrieving_a_User_Profile

Comment: I am sure I can get view counts calling the URL as in the example.  I am using Oauth2 authentication and the latest YT(v3) API and I believe I do not have to explicitly specify url..user.... I should be able to get the view counts for each video in the channel with the code in the question. Right now I am able to get a title, description ....

Answer (score 0):

using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;

using Google.Apis.Authentication;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth;
using Google.Apis.Samples.Helper;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util;
using Google.Apis.Youtube.v3;
using Google.Apis.Youtube.v3.Data;

var youtube = new YoutubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
      {
        Authenticator = auth
      });

var viewcount = youtube.Videos.List("enter video ID here", "statistics");